# Getting an error in function call r : Missing argument to function call

Tags: r

[image]

I am getting above mentioned error in R while creating trian data set.

Code:

```
 reg_train_df <- as.data.frame(train_df[,c("name",
                                        "price",
                                         "abtest",
                                         "vehicleType",
                                         "yearofRegistration",
                                         "gearbox",
                                         "powerPS",
                                         "model",
                                         "kilometer",
                                         "monthofRegistration",
                                         "fuelType",
                                         "brand",
                                         "notRepairedDamage",
                                          "postalCode",
                                        #"Log.price"
)])
```

Error:

```
Error in c("name", "price", "abtest", "vehicleType", "yearofRegistration", : argument 15 is empty
```

Show Traceback:

```
3.
[.data.frame`(train_df, , c("name", "price", "abtest", "vehicleType", "yearofRegistration", "gearbox", "powerPS", "model", "kilometer", "monthofRegistration", "fuelType", "brand", "notRepairedDamage", "postalCode", ))

2.
train_df[, c("name", "price", "abtest", "vehicleType", "yearofRegistration", "gearbox", "powerPS", "model", "kilometer", "monthofRegistration", "fuelType", "brand", "notRepairedDamage", "postalCode", )]

1.
as.data.frame(train_df[, c("name", "price", "abtest", "vehicleType", "yearofRegistration", "gearbox", "powerPS", "model", "kilometer", "monthofRegistration", "fuelType", "brand", "notRepairedDamage", "postalCode", )])
```

Please help to get rid of this error

Comment: If you have code snippets don't use 3 backticks like on GitHub it will not work (but single backticks will work but only inside text), on StackOverlow we have 4 space indent for code you can select text and use `{}` button. If you have JavaScript/CSS/HTML code you can also use stackSnippet that you can run from browser.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you forgot to remove the last comma.

For example this line

```
reg_train_df <- as.data.frame(train_df[,c("name", "price", "abtest", "vehicleType", "yearofRegistration", "gearbox", "powerPS", "model", "kilometer", "monthofRegistration", "fuelType", "brand", "notRepairedDamage", "postalCode", #"Log.price" )])
```

Should become:

```
   reg_train_df <- as.data.frame(train_df[,c("name", "price", "abtest", "vehicleType", "yearofRegistration", "gearbox", "powerPS", "model", "kilometer", "monthofRegistration", "fuelType", "brand", "notRepairedDamage", "postalCode" #"Log.price" 
    )])
```